# Facebook marketing API all adsets that ended 10 days back v2.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get all adsets that have an end_time  between today and 10 days back.

In the docs I found this field, end_time which I think is correct, right?.

[Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign)

However. How do I format this as a request?

If this where a campagin it would have the syntax

```
'time_range={"since":"2015-03-01","until":"2015-03-31"}'
```

Here is my current code example.

```
graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_xxxx/adsets?access_token=xxx&fields=name,effective_status,end_time&end_time=['since':'2015-03-01','until':'2015-03-31']
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it doesn't appear in the documentation, it should work the same way as the campaigns. According with SDK codebases, they admit "time_range" as a parameter in `get_ad_sets` method.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/master/facebookads/adobjects/adaccount.py#L707